# Creating Crosstab/Matrix KPI Report Showing Counts of Open Records Over Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS Report Builder 3.0 / SQL Server 2012 and I have a database of "ticket" records.  Each ticket has a status (simplified to open / closed), an origination date, and a completion date.  I've been asked to build a cross-tab report that returns the number of open records as of the last day of the month for the last 12 months.

I could easily provide a report that shows open items NOW.  I can also fairly easily calculate the number of open items on any given date (origination date <= @DATE, comp date > @date or comp date is null).  Using that logic, I could even define a dataset for each of the 12 periods for the given scope, but since each of those periods would be defined explicitly, they wouldn't be in the same field to use as the column group for the cross tab, so I don't know how I would actually be able to construct a single crosstab table that would summarize those results.

Anyone ever done anything like this and can share their method?

My most recent thought is to select each date period explicitly and combine them using unions and then use that as the basis for the report, but I'm having a tough time forcing my brain to congeal that concept into something I can execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the query from the perspective of the time period was the solution.

```
SELECT
    PERIOD_START
    ,COUNT (ACOUNT.ACTIVITY_ID) OPEN_ACT_COUNT

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-12,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-12,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-12,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-12,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-11,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-11,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-11,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-11,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-10,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-10,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-10,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-10,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-9,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-9,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-9,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-9,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-8,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-8,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-8,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-8,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-7,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-7,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-7,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-7,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-5,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-5,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-5,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-5,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-4,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-4,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-4,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-4,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-3,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-3,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-3,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-3,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-2,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-2,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-2,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-2,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-1,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-1,getdate())),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(yy,dateadd(mm,-1,getdate())),datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-1,getdate())),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
        UNION
        SELECT
            DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yy,getdate()),datepart(mm,getdate()),'01') AS PERIOD_START
            ,EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yy,getdate()),datepart(mm,getdate()),'01')) AS PERIOD_END
    ) PERIODS

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            AROOT.ACTIVITY_ID
            ,DACT_PARTY.ACT_OWNER_DEPT_GRP
            ,DACT_ORI.ACT_ORI_DATE
            ,DACT_COM.ACT_COM_DATE
            ,CASE WHEN AROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('01','02','03','04','60','63') THEN 'OPEN'
                WHEN AROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('06','07','09') THEN 'COMPLETE' END STATUS
        FROM
            DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT AROOT

            JOIN DM_IAM_D_I_ROOT IROOT ON IROOT.DB_KEY = AROOT.PAR_ISSUE_UUID AND IROOT.APPLICATION = 'QIM' AND IROOT.LCYCLE_CD NOT IN ('10', '64') AND IROOT.ZZCAP_FACILITY = CASE WHEN @FAC = 'MT' THEN 'N200' WHEN @FAC = 'PI' THEN 'N202' WHEN @FAC = 'HU' THEN 'N204' ELSE @FAC END

            OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT 
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY.PARENT_KEY
                    ,DM_BUT000.FIRST_LAST_NAME
                    ,NPDA.FLEET_ID
                    ,NPDA.DEPARTMENT
                    ,DEPTS.ZZCAP_OWED_TO_SUB_DEPT_DESC AS DEPT_DESC
                    ,DEPTS.ZZCAP_OWED_DEPT AS ACT_OWNER_DEPT_GRP
                    ,NPDA.SUPERVISOR

                FROM
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY
                    JOIN DM_BUT000 ON DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY.PARTNER_ID = DM_BUT000.PARTNER
                    JOIN DM_ADR6 ON DM_BUT000.PERSNUMBER = DM_ADR6.PERSNUMBER
                    JOIN NMC_PERSONNEL_DATA NPDA ON LEFT(DM_ADR6.SMTP_ADDR,40) = LEFT(NPDA.WORK_EMAIL,40)
                    JOIN DM_ZCAP_OWED_DEPT DEPTS ON NPDA.DEPARTMENT = DEPTS.ZZCAP_OWED_TO_SUB_DEPT
                WHERE
                    AROOT.DB_KEY = DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY.PARENT_KEY AND AROOT.MANDT = DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY.MANDT
                    AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_PARTY.PARTY_ROLE_CODE IN ('ACTDRIVR', 'ZASSIGN', 'ZACTAPP')
            ) AS DACT_PARTY

            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.PARENT_KEY
                    ,DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,4),RIGHT(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,6),2),RIGHT(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,8),2)) AS ACT_ORI_DATE
                FROM
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE 
                WHERE
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.ROLE_CD = 'ORI'
                    AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME > 19000000000000
            ) DACT_ORI ON AROOT.DB_KEY = DACT_ORI.PARENT_KEY 

            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.PARENT_KEY
                    ,DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,4),RIGHT(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,6),2),RIGHT(LEFT(DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME,8),2)) AS ACT_COM_DATE
                FROM
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE 
                WHERE
                    DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.ROLE_CD = 'COM'
                    AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_DATE.DATE_TIME > 19000000000000
            ) DACT_COM ON AROOT.DB_KEY = DACT_COM.PARENT_KEY 

        WHERE
            AROOT.ACT_TEMPLATE IN (' ', 'CA', 'CAPR', 'CCA', 'FBC-TEMP', 'FBD-TEMP', 'MRA', 'OBD-TEMP', 'OBN_OBD_CO', 'OBN_OBD_FB', 'OBN-TEMP', 'IA')
            AND AROOT.LCYCLE_CD NOT IN ('10','64')
            AND AROOT.LONG_TERM <> 'X'


    ) ACOUNT ON ACOUNT.ACT_ORI_DATE <= PERIOD_END AND (ACOUNT.STATUS = 'OPEN' OR ACOUNT.ACT_COM_DATE >= PERIOD_END)

GROUP BY PERIOD_START
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work? This query takes all the cases with status 'open' from last year then groups them by months.

```sql
select EOMONTH(completionDate), count(*)
from data
where ticketStatus = 'open' and completionDate > EOMONTH(DateAdd(Year, -1, GETDATE())
group by EOMONTH(completionDate)
```

You can play with the `completionDate > EOMONTH(DateAdd(Year, -1, GETDATE())` condition depending whtat exactly do you need.

Comment: No, because the status could be closed for the current period, but open in previous periods.  I need each record that was open during a given months to contribute to the open count for that period, but not in periods following where it closed.

Comment: But this is on the right track. You need to find the set of dates - which can be adapted from the where/group logic and then join / count. And consider that there might not be any "open" tickets on a given date.

Comment: Yes, this is the track I'm currently chasing.

Comment: You can find many discussion about calendar tables by searching. You need a subset of the calendar for the period of interest. One simple way is like this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=49ee9b953eca8bc739e946b8e9c1060f). With that you just join to your source data using your origination and completion dates.

Comment: And one trick is to remember that every month has a first day, but the last day varies. You could easily calculate the first day of every month in a period and then join in a slightly different manner. With monthstart date (x), use `where origination < x and x <= completion`.

Comment: And one more comment - a proper calendar table would allow you to run this query easily for the last "business" day of any month. An actual calendar has many advantages. As we can see from the current corona virus problem, sometimes a business is closed on days that would otherwise be considered work days.

Comment: I assume the data is versioned by months and after case has been closes the id doesn't appear for the next months. Could you give me an example where my query won't work but the recursive cte will? Maybe you can add some sample data to the post

Comment: The data is not versioned.  The record only exists in the root table once based on its current status.  So, I can group the completion dates by month, as you suggested and that will show me throughput of completed records, but it won’t help me report on how many records were open during that period.  I revised the original post with some code I’m playing with.

Comment: Updated code with my "final" query.  It displays what I think should be the correct counts.

Comment: The code it's to case specific for me to give any comments. You could write PERIODS recursively this will make it easier to extend for 24 months etc. You could also merge DACT_ORI and DACT_COM to one subquery (if the optimized didn't do so already). Double check if you shouldn't do `COUNT (distinct ACOUNT.ACTIVITY_ID)` DACT_COM could give multiple rows per month for the same case. If you want I can put my comments in the anwser